# IIS cannot run unpacked web app

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have unpacked a web application in a folder. It contains dll's, configuration files and the `wwwroot` directory. Then I have created an IIS web application pointing to the previous folder. When I browsed the page I got a `HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error`. The error code is `0x8007000d`. Then I clicked on "View more information" and it says that either ApplicationHost.config or the Web.config file contain a malformed XML element. The problem is that my Web.config file does not contain malformed elements and I do not have a ApplicationHost.config file in my folder.

Comment: when this happened with me i recreated the web app using web sites because in my case it could've happened and it worked like a charm, i don't know if in your case you can do the same

Comment: But did you create a new web site with IIS or with Visual Studio?

Comment: visual studio, asp.net website and looked upon the small differences between the two when copying and pasting the old code and at the end i used IIS and it worked.

Comment: Do you have the application pool set to use the correct .NET framework version?

Comment: I use asp.net core so what .net clr version should I set for the application pool: 2, 4, or no managed code?

Comment: @nix86 2 would be wrong, and core is managed code, so... try 4.